# Scrollable interface?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

is it possible to create a scrollable interface in blender UI ?
let say in this code below

```
... ui code ...
box= layout.box()
for i in range(999) :
    layout.label(text=str(i))
```

that the box have a fixed size with a scrolling ability ? 
 does that exist in blender ? i don't remember scouting this in the api

something more simple than an UI list. as Ui list require collection or group properties that need to be constantly updated. the code need to stay procedural.

Comment: Digging through the interface classes code, so far i found mainly that the MAX count is rarely found, rather it's looking very much like make space for what's needed, while i found "#define PIE_MAX_ITEMS 8". Scrollable, well the source code makes me believe that as long as there is something to scroll for, you get your scrollbar, but if you think about the panels or views, they so far never fell short on displaying anything that was there, i'd say blender is written with as open limits as possible.

Comment: interresting, what do you propose ?

Comment: I only really combed through the codes out of curiosity myself after reading the question, the fact that blender keeps scrolling as long as there is a button or node in the view made me interested. My question would be what you have in mind, as a list of procedural generated buttons or labels seem to be more like a placeholder. While it should most likely be no problem for the pointers in the code to just iterate through all your labels and scroll them if needed, i do wonder what you had in mind. Since you said "something more simple than the UI list. It's handled, as a list of ui elements.

Comment: [interface_API](https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blob/master/doc/guides/interface_API.txt) should also help understand it a bit better, at least in regards of structure and design.

Comment: With many editors open it's possible to scroll their bottom bars with the mouse wheel when the mouse is over them. I think that's all you can do.